# How to dynamically add text to textarea while recording via webkitspeech with Angular 2?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Currently, I record my voice with this simple code in Angular Component

```
speechToText() {
    const {webkitSpeechRecognition}: IWindow = <IWindow>window;
    const recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

    recognition.lang = 'en-US';
    recognition.continuous = true;
    recognition.interimResults = true;

    recognition.onresult = event => {
      for (let i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
        this.interim_transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript;
      }
    };

    recognition.onerror = event => {
      console.log('Error occured', event);
    };

    recognition.start();
  }
}
```

And in my HTML I have the value bind to the interim result

```
<textarea #description mdInput rows="5" placeholder="Short Story" name="description" [value]="interim_transcript"></textarea>
```

The problem, however, is that I can see the text being put into the textarea only after I click on the textarea or outside of it to trigger dom update. How to make it update textarea as soon as I begin saying words giving this live text update, same way as here https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html

Comment: can you show your angular component?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Angular is not aware of the update to `interim_transcript` since it happens outside of what the Zone is aware of.

I see two immediate ways to fix it:

- Run the `interim_transcript` update in a `zone.run` call. See [NgZone](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html) in the docs.
- Make `interim_transcript` an [Observable](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html). Actually a [Subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html), but the point is that it needs to be *observable*.

I'd recommend the latter, and it basically involves this:

1. When you define `interim_transcript`, define it like this: `interim_transcript: new Subject<string>()`
2. When you update it in the `onresult` callback, replace

`this.interim_transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript;`

with

`this.interim_transcript.next(event.results[i][0].transcript);`

3. Change the `value` binding in your template, replace:

`[value]="interim_transcript"`

with

`[value]="interim_transcript | async"`

Observables are an incredibly powerful concept that can make your code more easy to reason about (even though it seems very odd at first). It can boost your performance significantly when you start using the `OnPush` change detection mechanism. Finally, however cheesy it sounds, can change the way you think about your programs, to a data stream mind model instead of state updates. This will likely sound confusing and weird, but I strongly recommend looking into it, I'm sure it will pay off.

Here are a few good resources to get started:

[Using Observable](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html) from Rangle.io.

[Understand and Utilize the Async Pipe in Angular 2](http://briantroncone.com/?p=623) from Brian Troncone

Comment: Thanks a lot for a very informative answer, I will definitely take a look at those 2 links you provided, however, the issue remains. I made the changes you mentioned however the content of the textarea is still not being updated. Here is component code https://gist.github.com/Nikki1993/d69d490469ad3990d928b3cdcf2f5b12 and I added the async pipe tot he value, still the same.

Comment: To add to it, I can see updates if I constantly move my mouse pointer all the time, but if I keep it still and just press the record button, there is no visual refresh.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a plunker replicating the issue?

Comment: Here is a plunker. Had to stuff textToSpeech function call into OnInit otherwise plunker reloaded every time I tried to call it :P so start speaking straight away http://plnkr.co/edit/8uzSHELOYD00YpG32hGJ?p=preview